# Asset bundle not loading because of platform incompatibility

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have an android app made with Unity and whenever I try to load my asset bundles inside unity I get this error :
[image: logs]

my build API level

[image: API]

however I built my asset bundles in API Level 16 and when I build the app with API Level 16 & 19 doesnt make difference still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states that you are trying to load an asset bundle in android platform which is not build for android platform. Please use below code for specific platform. I am sure you have follow [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html) which by default builds for windows only.

```
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

public class CreateAssetBundles
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
    static void BuildAllAssetBundles()
    {
        string assetBundleDirectory = "Assets/AssetBundles";
        if(!Directory.Exists(assetBundleDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(assetBundleDirectory);
        }
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(assetBundleDirectory, 
                                        BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, 
                                        EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget);
    }
}
```

This code will build asset bundle for current selected platform.